# signed int to unsigned byte and vice versa

Tags: java, byte, int, pixel, unsigned

I have a signed value e.g. **-7368817**
when I cast it to byte it will be something like: **-113**
I convert it to unsigned byte bye `& 0xff` and it will be something like **143**
now I manipulate this byte value and after that I want to whole way back! to get the signed integer of the new byte. :)

**Update**

**The whole story:**

I have an image which is 8-bit depth and gray scale! it means that all pixels are presented using 1 byte

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File("my_grayscal_8bit_photo.jpg"));

int intPixel = image.getRGB(1, 1);
```

now I need some bit manipulation in this pixel but since it is int I must convert it to byte first:

```
byte bytePixel = (byte) intPixel;
```

and to make it unsigned:

```
int intPixel2 = bytePixel & 0xff;
```

now I do my bit manipulation and want to convert it to int and do:

```
image.setRGB(1, 1, neworiginalint);
```

Comment: I assume you are aware that java doesn't have unsigned types (apart from char)

Comment: And that a byte can only hold 256 values i.e. 2^8 as its 8-bit. IMHO you can use byte as unsigned if you want, you just won't get much help from Java.

Comment: What should be the outcome of the last conversion from byte to int? As the whole value range of byte fits into int it would still be 143?
What exactly do you want to do by this conversions?

Comment: BTW: What would be the point of having a 4-byte `int` if you could fit every possible value into a 1-byte `byte` ;)

Comment: I know that Java has no unsigned type, so I put the unsigned byte in an int.

Comment: I'm assuming that you actually intend to maintain a grayscale image. In which case you need to manipulate all three of the red, green and blue channels of the `BufferedImage`. Even though you're dealing with a grayscale image, getRGB() and setRGB() are dealing with ARGB int pixels. If you only change what you get from `& 0xFF` you'll only be affecting the blue channel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`getRGB(int x, int y)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#getRGB%28int,%20int%29) method *always* returns an `int` pixel in the [`TYPE_INT_ARGB`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#TYPE_INT_ARGB) color model. To manually extract the red, green, blue and alpha values for the pixel you can do this:

```
int pixel = image.getRGB(1, 1);
int a = (pixel >> 24) & 0xFF;
int r = (pixel >> 16) & 0xFF;
int g = (pixel >> 8) & 0xFF;
int b = pixel & 0xFF;
```

Or use the [`Color(int rgba, boolean hasalpha)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html) constructor for convenience (at the cost of performance). Once you've manipulated the red, green, blue and alpha values (in the range of 0 to 255) you can recombine them back into an `int` for setting pixels:

```
int newPixel = (a << 24) | (r << 16) | (g << 8) | b;
```

Using the -7368817 pixel you mentioned with this code, the alpha is 255 (so no transparency) and the red, green and blue values are all 143. Since you're dealing with grayscale you could just pick any of red, green or blue to get the gray value. However on setting the pixel you're going to have set all three to maintain the grayscale since it's RGB. You could shortcut it a bit like so:

```
int pixel = image.getRGB(1, 1);

// extract your gray value from blue, assume red and green are same
int gray = pixel & 0xFF; 

// this method does your manipulation on the gray value, 0 to 255
gray = manipulate(gray);

// recombine back into int, preserving the original alpha
int newPixel = (pixel & 0xFF000000) | (gray << 16) | (gray << 8) | gray;

// now you can set your new pixel
image.setRGB(1, 1, nexPixel);
```

Basically the trick is to use `int` as your unsigned byte. Just make sure you keep the values from 0 to 255 and everything should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Are you asking how to manipulate the least-significant byte in an signed int, without touching  the more significant byte?
This can be done like this:

```
int i = -7368817; // 0xFF8F 8F8F
int b = i & 0xFF; // "signed byte", = 0x8F = 143
b += 0x2C; // your manipulation, result = 0xBB
i = (i & 0xFFFFFF00) | (b & 0xFF); // result of LSB modification = 0xFF8F8FBB
```

or in one step: `i = (i & 0xFFFFFF00) | ((i + 0x2C) & 0xFF);` if it is a simple manipulation.

If the manipulation can't ever produce an overflow, you can simply do it on the whole int:
`i ^= 0x34; // i = 0xFF8F8FBB`